# Which log files do I look at to debug copy/paste and Klipper?

Tags: logs, kde, debugging, clipboard, manjaro

**Short Version**
What log files do I look at to monitor copy/paste actions? And what logs do I look at to monitor all Klipper actions?

**Long Version**
After using my desktop for a while (could be a few hours, could be a few minutes), copy paste starts doing strange things. When I copy (Ctrl+C or via right click menu), Klipper will sometimes not pick up the highlighted text. It sometimes gets blank lines, sometimes just jumps to a random entry in the history, and sometimes works. Rebooting "fixes" it but after some time, this issue will always return.

As far as I can tell, my system was perfectly fine until a couple months ago when I first noticed the issue. But since it is random and rebooting resets the issue, I have no idea what update might have caused this. So I'm trying to debug and track down the issue myself. With that said, could anyone tell me every possible log file to look at that's related to copy/paste and klipper? Thanks!

**System Info**: In case this reminds someone of a similar issue, my OS is Netrunner Rolling (this is based off Manjaro), CPU is Intel, and GPU is a Radeon HD 7750 using the open source drivers.

Comment: No, I can't tell you where klipper puts its logs. Copy paste something and search your home directory for recently changed files. BTW thanks are not appropriate for this site.

Comment: @anyone - Already tried that with /home and /var/log and it turned up nothing which is why I'm asking here. Also, there's nothing in the rules saying you can't be polite and say thanks/thank you. A lot of people say that at the end of their submissions. This is actually the first time I've seen someone complain about it in my 5+ years of being on the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: With a remote desktop I sometimes have issues that get fixed by pressing CTRL-ALT-SHFT or CTRL. Does this work-around help you a little?

Comment: @WalterA Sorry no. Also, I'm not connecting to a system via remote desktop. This is straight up on normal hardware. I am curious, what does that work around do?

Comment: A windows keyboard can give codes that the remote session doesn't process correctly. Don't ask me exactly, see https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/cbaae74e-8311-4a46-a842-31dcdd6878dc/windows-key-stuck?forum=winserverTS or http://superuser.com/questions/5480/remote-desktop-pressing-windows-key-randomly

Comment: I see. Reading through it, it seems to have no relation to my issue (Linux, no remote session, etc.). Thanks for trying though.

Comment: For Klipper, has anyone tried to look to source code? https://projects.kde.org/projects/kde/kde-workspace/repository/revisions/master/show/plasma-workspace/klipper

Comment: In case any software starts to randomly behave incorrectly, it's typically caused by memory corruption and log files typically do not help. There are no quick ways to fix this class of problems (typically buffer overflow, double free or incorrect pointer arithmetic) so there are no silver bullets to solve the issue. Klipper is written in C++ so it's prone to have any memory safety issues in case of a even a minor programming error.

Answer (score 0):

For sure it does not "log" in a dedicated log-file by default.

However, you *may* see something useful in `~/.xsession-errors`. Run `tail -f ~/.xsession-errors` on a console while you play with klipper.

You may also communicate with klipper over dbus, but I don't see any logging facility there either (but you can list the entries, clear the history, etc etc)

Comment: Sorry no. As mentioned in the comments, I've already been checking the /home and /var/log directories for changes when trying to find logging sources. Tried it again just now to confirm and xsession-errors does not show anything. I put the bounty on this asking for sources specifically because all I get are guess answers like this.

Also, if it does not log by default, is there any documentation showing how I can turn on logging? Where did you find this out? Is there any documentation on this anywhere?

Comment: I did check the sources (kde-workspace 4.11.13 in Debian) and i don't see any logging facility for run-time except for some uses of `kWarning` in case of problems (ie, not for every single mouse selection). However, you can enable debugging info at compile time if you `#define NOISY_KLIPPER`. This debug info goes via `kDebug`.